# Find maximum value which can be obtained when e is in XO with any node from d to the root

Tags: c++

I just came along this problem. But couldn't think of any solution hence reaching out to the community.
There are C queries and for each query you are given two integers d (the node number) and e and you have to find the maximum value when e is "xord" with any of the ancestors of d or d itself.
Formally, find the maximum value which can be obtained when e is "xord" with any node in the path from d to root. "XOR" is bitwise "XOR" operator.

Please help

Comment: What have you done so far to solve your problem? Post the code you tried and didn't work.

Comment: Can you give an example? Let's say d=5 and e=11. What then?

Comment: This, as most questions which give a strong impression of being a homework dump, lacks focus on the specific programming problem you encountered while trying yourself. To improve have a look at the compromise described here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions and at [ask].